# RedisML: More complex Machine Learning models?

Tags: machine-learning, redis, redisml

I am looking for the use of RedisML for more complex machine learning models like, XGBoost and LSTM. Is there any plan from the RedisML team to incorporate these complex ML module in there `modelu.so`?

Comment: I suggest you ask that on the project repo.

Comment: Project repo means github rt?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: @kadsank did you check RedisTF? (https://github.com/lantiga/RedisTF)